# can't access with FTP using terminal

Tags: ftp

I was wondering why I can't connect through Terminal to my FTP server.

It perfectly works through filezilla, output from terminal is

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 16:53. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:root): username
331 User username OK. Password required
Password:
530 Login authentication failed
Login failed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

note i am using putty to connect to my server and then whilst in my server i am trying to ftp to the next server

Comment: And Pure-FTPd does not log a reason for rejecting your login attempt?

Comment: i dont have access to the other server

Comment: Is your username 'username'? And when you type your password just in a putty (not in the FTP client), does it contain errors in characters?